# How to calculate the value (wind direction) of "maximal effect" in a linear-circular correlation?

Tags: correlation, python, scipy, circular-statistics, environmental-data

I am trying to evaluate the effect of wind direction (circular variable) on a dependent linear variable. I have used circular-linear regression to find the correlation coefficient between the two variables, shown in the code sample below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats

data = pd.read_csv('Data_example.csv')

x = data.Rate # dependent linear variable
theta = data.WindDir_deg * (3.14159265359/180) # corresponding measured wind directions (converted to radians)

rxc = np.array(sp.stats.pearsonr(x,np.cos(theta)))
rxs = np.array(sp.stats.pearsonr(x,np.sin(theta)))
rcs = np.array(sp.stats.pearsonr(np.cos(theta),np.sin(theta)))

rho = np.sqrt(((rxc)**2 + (rxs)**2 - (rxc)*(rxs)*(rcs)) / (1 - (rcs)**2))

print("Correlation coefficient, ", rho)
```

Example Data

```
     Rate       WindDir_deg
0   -0.102186   180
1   -0.051093   200
2   -0.026898   40
3   -0.012773   180
4   -0.004927   0
5   -0.002488   50
6   0.000000    180
7   0.000000    160
8   0.000000    180
9   0.018639    170
10  0.019800    320
11  0.021236    160
12  0.025028    20
13  0.026400    240
14  0.030280    160
15  0.033402    150
16  0.037174    190
17  0.040175    180
18  0.041331    160
19  0.049942    190
20  0.051093    120
21  0.052635    140
22  0.052800    360
23  0.057955    170
24  0.057955    170
25  0.057955    30
26  0.059413    330
27  0.060490    170
28  0.060560    20
29  0.063866    190
30  0.070678    170
31  0.072444    240
32  0.085714    160
33  0.101950    0
34  0.105600    0
35  0.110216    40
36  0.120980    180
37  0.121660    170
38  0.145200    10
39  0.173865    180
40  0.204372    180
41  0.242240    30
42  0.351462    180
43  0.360800    170
44  0.423920    30
45  0.592800    160
46  0.741000    190
47  1.937873    170
```

Now how do I estimate the actual wind direction that has the maximal effect on the linear variable? For example in the data shown in this plot, the wind direction with maximal effect on the linear variable appears to be somewhere between 150° and 200°, but how to I calculate this mathematically?

[image]

Comment: Isn't this a restatement of your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568870/how-can-i-quantify-this-non-linear-relationship-where-y-values-peak-within-a-nar?

Comment: No not exactly. My previous question was asking how to quantify a relationship between the two variables, which I have now done by calculating the correlation coefficient (see code example). This new question is asking specifically how to estimate the actual value (degree direction) that has the maximal effect on the linear variable.

Comment: Can you make your code reproducible, by making your dataset available?

Comment: Of course. I have edited my question to include a snippet of the dataset

Comment: For future readers: I recommend horizontal axis labels 0(45)360 not 0(50)350.  Text such as N NE ... NW may make more sense too.

Answer (score 0):

The circular-linear correlation coefficient is the square-root of the fraction of variance explained by a linear model

$$x = a \cos(\theta) + b \sin(\theta) + c$$

Fit this regression with least squares and obtain $(a,b)$. The direction where $x$ is the largest should then be $\tan^{-1}(b/a)$. Use `arctan2(b,a)` to calculate this. Alternatively, you can view $a + ib$ as a complex number, and recover the phase via `np.angle(a+1j*b)`. (Incidentally, the magnitude $|a + ib|$ captures the depth of modulation and is vaguely analogous to slope in linear regression).

Comment: Why would this estimate the direction of "maximum effect", especially with a distribution that empirically looks multimodal?

Comment: I think you're right. Things also get awkward when data are limited and $\theta$ isn't sampled uniformly. IMO the linear regression is clearer, but you need to be careful. If you want the best R² on your data, then you fit this with OLS, which will react to induced correlations in the sine and cosine of θ. But, if you want a "ground truth" estimate of best direction, we *know* that sine/cosine will be zero mean, uncorrelated, and have variance ½. IMO this is feels better in some sense, and the circular-linear correlation seems worryingly biased.